# Dataframe a partir de coincidencias en una lista con colnames

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, dataframe, table

Estoy tratando de construir un Dataframe de una única fila del tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Genero el dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']), index ={'consulta1'})
```

y por otro lado tengo una lista que quiero comparar, de dimensiones distintas al número de columnas tal que:

```
consulta1 = ['N','C','D','F','H']
```

He tratado de hacerlo creando una tabla previamente pero tampoco he conseguido incluírla en el dataframe.

```
    table = []
for elem in consulta1:
  if elem in df.columns:
    table.append(1)
  else:
    table.append(0)
table
```

Lo que obtiene como resultado:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Pero al no tener el mismo tamaño tengo problemas para pasarlo al dataframe.

Comment: `[int(x in consulta1) for x in df.columns]`

Comment: más concretamente sería `df.loc["consulta1",:] = [int(x in consulta1) for x in df.columns]`

Comment: Gracias @Christian

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar con un poco de manejo de datos.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])
consulta2 = ['N','C','D','F','H']
vec=np.zeros(len(df.columns))
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
 for j in range(len(consulta2)):
   if df.columns[i]==consulta2[j]:
     vec[i]=1
vec=pd.DataFrame(vec).transpose()
vec.columns=['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
df=df.append(vec, ignore_index=True)
df[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

[image: Resultado en colab]

Comment: has visto mi comentario? todo lo que haces es totalmente innecesario, todo se resuelve en 1 línea de código